# SQL Query Grab 2 different Ids same table, join and query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Trying to take ID 2 and ID 3 Join them.

So grab 2 columns from table, ID and query, grab the 2 different IDs from table and then join them together.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.SQLQuery
FROM (SELECT ID, SQLQuery
      FROM dbo.ReportQuery
      WHERE (ID = 2)) AS a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID, SQLQuery
            FROM dbo.ReportQuery AS ReportQuery_1
            WHERE (ID = 3)) AS b ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Sample Data

Here is some sample data. Trying to grab ID=2, and ID=3 and combine them into a single statement.

```
    ID     SQLQuery
    1      Select * from users where plc_id like @PLC_ID
    2      Select * from stepgrouplog where (EndDateTime = '2009')
    3      Select * from tmp_kosherStatus where unit=@unit
```

Comment: Please re-format your sql code, and ask a question or tell us what is the problem.

Comment: can you show some sample data and your desired output?

Comment: How could it be `a.ID = b.ID` when you filter `a.ID = 2` AND `b.ID = 3`?

Comment: Is it like you want to join means add/concatenate two sql queries at id 2 and 3 into one string? as table operator join doesn't seem to fulfill any significant purpose here.

Comment: @Deepshikha Yes, that is what I am attempting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as:

```
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(4000);
SELECT @SQLString = COALESCE(@SQLString + '; ', '') + SQLQuery 
FROM table1
where id in (2,3)

select @SQLString
```